# Show a static text on StatusBar in android

Tags: android

I want to implement something like this in my StatusBar...[image]

I saw several examples and all use the notification class but I do not want it to appear as an event, I just want the text as in the gif.

[image]

Comment: You better off using SnackBar for this sort of things. It's easy to implement and gives better user experience in my opinion.

https://developer.android.com/training/snackbar/action.html

Answer (score 1):

Check this link [Status Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html)

You can coordinate with the visibility of status bar and put your custom layout there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this by your own code. You can create a custom view as according to you.  But the only issue will arrive will be the shadow on `StatusBar`.

You can not add any view on the `StatusBar`. But you can add a view behind the icons.

You can hide the background of status by adding this line:

```
Window w = context.getWindow();
w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
```

Comment: Ok I thing that I Can hide the statusbar and show a element or view with the text...

Answer (score 0):

Android does not support this, sorry.